# Getting mailaddresses out of recipients of an mailItem

Tags: vba, outlook

I been trying to find out a way to find out which mail addresses a mail has been sent to. Consider the following:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim mai As MailItem
    Dim intInitial As Integer
    Dim intFinal As Integer
    Dim strEntryId As String
    Dim intLength As Integer
    
    intInitial = 1
    intLength = Len(EntryIDCollection)
    intFinal = InStr(intInitial, EntryIDCollection, ",")
    Do While intFinal <> 0
        strEntryId = Strings.Mid(EntryIDCollection, intInitial, (intFinal - intInitial))
        Set mai = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strEntryId)
        intInitial = intFinal + 1
        intFinal = InStr(intInitial, EntryIDCollection, ",")
    Loop
    strEntryId = Strings.Mid(EntryIDCollection, intInitial, (intLength - intInitial) + 1)
    MsgBox strEntryId
    Set mai = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strEntryId)
    For Each Recipient In mai.Recipients
        MsgBox Recipient
    Next
End sub
```

In those msgBoxes I get the "nice name", Like "John Doe" - but I want to get the mail address, "john.doe@gmail.com".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume this is Outlook 2007+. Have you tried the [Address Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175708%28v=office.12%29.aspx)?

```
For Each Recipient In mai.Recipients
  MsgBox Recipient.Address
Next Recipient
```

This should print the email address of each recipient.

Comment: That is an correct assumption. I'm using Outlook 2010. I will test this right away. Thanks!